# Filling in a column in SQL with a Case_when

Tags: sql, case

So I have a column called censusbloccode2. I have just read this in from a fixed width file. The desired task is to have it to the following

```
If censusbloccode2 is blank then input a "0". If it has anything in it.. then leave it alone
```

When I broke up the fixed width text file... it is designated as a char (1) if that helps.

All of the search results that I have seen query this using a select.

Comment: what is meant by "input a '0'"? Input where? Also I don't see why it is relevant or even what you mean by breaking up the width text file and it being designated as a char(1) ... how did you break up a width text file (assume you mean fixed-width text file) into one character?

Comment: @topsail. What is meant is to have the column value be a zero. The column can't be blank.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be `update Table set Field = '0' where len(Field) = 0`